# HTTPS by default for a single website on Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, wamp

I have a WAMP server with a few sites on it. I would like to enable SSL for default for only one of the sites.

While the https://www.example.com is accessible, there is no auto redirect happening for http://www.example.com.

Also `httpd -t` shows `Syntax Ok`
Please help.

This is my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin hi@santo.sh
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/example"
    ServerName http://manage.example.com/
    ServerAlias http://manage.example.com/   
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin hi@santo.sh
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/example/public"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile "C:/wamp/OpenSSL/cert/sslcert.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/wamp/OpenSSL/certs/mydomain.key" 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: In which way is it not working?

Comment: Fixed. The redirect's not working.

Answer (score 0):

This questions was answered well on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/733254/configure-https-by-default-for-a-single-site-on-server)

This part is wrong.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

While there are many choices available: here's the best one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com 
    # [ Http to Https ]
    Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```